# How to I delete all Flask sessions?

Tags: python, session, flask

How do I delete all sessions and cookies set by my Flask/python app. So that when users return they have to re-login. I want to do this each time I push a new version of the code to production otherwise.

Comment: You could try changing your secret_key for each deployment. Otherwise, I don't think you have many options.

Comment: If you store your sessions in Redis, you could just wipe them all.

Comment: There are many options to store it, there are modules to save them in files and database, I mean, the same database you use for the other data. No real need to add Redis to your setup. I won't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Best way I found is to invalidate the secret key like so

```
app.secret_key = os.urandom(32)
```

The key is secure enough, and each time you launch your system the key changes invalidating all sessions.